# Abstract Entity and typealias for editing NSManagedObject?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm attempting to make a viewController that handles editing of two different entities that both have the same abstract parent entity.

I'm curious if this is possible? Since I believe abstract entities are not supposed to be initialized? Or if there was a better way of doing it with something like typealias?

At the moment, I currently have a lazy variable for both children entities, and am setting up the VC based off of a switch statement on the VC that performed the segue. All of this is also inside of a child context.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what attributes you want to edit in this view controller, and how complex you want the view controller to be.

If you only want to edit attributes that belong to the abstract parent, then it should be easy. Give the view controller a variable of the same type as the abstract parent. Then assign any sub-entity instance to that variable. As a trivial example, maybe your parent entity is `Building` and you have sub-entities called `House` and `Restaurant`. Your view controller only edits the address, which is part of `Building`. So, add a variable to the view controller of type `Building` and then assign either a `House` or a `Restaurant` as the value, and it should just work. You never create an instance of `Building` directly, but since the others inherit from it, you can have a variable with that type.

If you need to edit attributes that belong to the sub-entities, it's more complex. Your view controller would need to detect the specific entity so that it would know what can be edited. Unless the two child entities are very similar, that could get messy.

Comment: Hey Tom, Thank you very much. That's along the lines of what I'm trying to do. It makes total sense, I just wasn't sure it was possible although I assumed. - One last question, I'm assuming all the other details stay the same? Even the one's that or specific to the sub-entity? Since they are not changed. Is that correct?

Comment: If you don't change the attribute values, they don't change.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Time to refactor!